# SHA512 hash in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, sha512

i have a code for generating SHA512 hash of a string in excel, but on some notebook, it runs into error thanks to a net framework related problem. I have came accross a solution recently; when I open the "Me" expression in the locals window, the code can run without any error.

Locals:
[image]

Is there any chance to insert an additional code which can expand the "Me" expression in locals when i start running my VBA code in excel?

```
Sub sha512_kodolas()

Sheets("a").Range("a1").Value = h512(Sheets("b").Range("c1").Value)

End Sub

Function h512(ByVal S As String) As String
  'https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha512managed.aspx

  Static UTF8 As Object, SHA As Object
  Dim Data, Temp, i As Long
  If SHA Is Nothing Then

    Set UTF8 = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
    Set SHA = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed")

  End If

  Data = SHA.ComputeHash_2(UTF8.GetBytes_4(S))
  ReDim Temp(LBound(Data) To UBound(Data)) As String
  For i = LBound(Data) To UBound(Data)
    Temp(i) = Right$("0" & Hex(Data(i)), 2)

  Next
  h512 = Join(Temp, "")

End Function
```

Comment: hmmm that's a first one :)  Can you share the code so I can test it?

Comment: Hello, i insterted the code in the original post!

Comment: ok unable to reproduce issue. BTW what did you mean by `thanks to a net framework related problem`?

Comment: the required net framework version is missing from these notebooks (and unfortunately we cant fix this problem for now) therefore i need a code to switch treeview in the locals...but im not sure it is possible or not

Comment: And what is the required version?

Comment: 2.0 and 3.5. currently the 4.0 version is installed

Comment: are you sure about that? I do not have 2.0/3.5 or even 4.0. I have 4.5 and it works. I have a feeling that it has nothing to do with the Dot Net Framework. There is something else into play here

Comment: yes, i'm sure about the missing net framework causes the "out of memory" error message. what do you think about my original question expanding the "me" expression in locals? is it possible?

Comment: `is it possible? – r92` Honestly? I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

could you try this code: https://github.com/krijnsent/crypto_vba -> download the excel and try the ComputeHash_C function? It's also carrying out the SHA512 encryption, but in a slightly different way from yours, so I'm curious to know if it also crashes?

Comment: hello, i tried this code, but runs into an error, too. "run-time error -2146232576 (80131700) automation error

Answer (score 0):

I tried the suggestion from the author above and it works like a charm: "*could you try this code: https://github.com/krijnsent/crypto_vba -> download the excel and try the ComputeHash_C function? It's also carrying out the SHA512 encryption, but in a slightly different way from yours, so I'm curious to know if it also crashes?*".
Simply clone the Github project, copy the following functions into your Excel workbook:

- Function ComputeHash_C(Meth As String, ByVal clearText As String, ByVal key As String, Optional OutType As String) As Variant
- Function ConvToBase64String(vIn As Variant) As Variant
- Function ConvToHexString(vIn As Variant) As Variant
- Function Base64Decode(ByVal base64String)
- Function Base64Encode(inData)

It works perfectly well! Thanks for sharing this code!

Comment: Within Excel you can use this then like a normal function: =ComputeHash_C("SHA512";"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";"";"STRHEX") which will compute the hash: 91ea1245f20d46ae9a037a989f54f1f790f0a47607eeb8a14d12890cea77a1bbc6c7ed9cf205e67b7f2b8fd4c7dfd3a7a8617e45f3c463d481c7e586c39ac1ed

Answer (score 0):

Using the Excel file from  https://github.com/krijnsent/crypto_vba, it works for me if I use commas rather than semicolons in the formula: =ComputeHash_C("SHA512",A3,"","STRHEX"). This is just a small variation on what Luc Krolls has posted.